# Como executar um código ao clicar em um link?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou criando um site que vai ter um sistema de login. Ao se logar no site, terá vários produtos lá dentro, um do lado do outro...

Cada produto vai ter seu valor, e cada usuário vai ter um crédito para poder gastar no site...

Ao clicar em algum produto, ele vai ser selecionado, vai ter que pegar o valor de produto, verificar se atingiu o seu limite de crédito, se atingiu, vai ter que mostrar uma mensagem na tela, se não atingiu, o usuário pode selecionar outro produto...

Exemplo:

O plano do usuário é de R$ 30,00 reais de crédito para gastar.

O usuário escolheu um produto com o valor de: R$ 15,00. O sistema vai pegar este valor e verificar se atingiu o limite do plano dele, se não atingiu, ele pode continuar selecionando os produtos, se ele selecionar outro produto, mas o valor dele for R$ 20,00, aí vai mostrar uma mensagem na tela, dizendo que passou do limite.

Como que eu posso fazer isso?

Poderia fornecer um exemplo funcional aqui?

Comment: A pergunta está um pouco ampla demais. Você poderia deixar mais específica dizendo em que ponto está a sua dificuldade? Comprar valores? Tratar o clique? Comunicar com o servidor? Da maneira como está, parece um pedido de código que resolva tudo isso de uma vez, o que não é adequado para o formato do site. Obrigado.

Comment: Uma sugestão: ao fazer o logon, já deixe uma variável de sessão com o valor do crédito do usuário. Em javascript, você controla para cada clique num produto o valor do crédito.

Answer (score 1):

Isso vai checar se o saldo é igual ao preço do produto:

```
if ($precodoproduto == "'.$saldo.'") {
    --------- Resposta depois da escolha do produto -----------
    }
```

Lembrando que você deve criar uma função pra tirar o saldo e utiliza-lá na resposta da página.

Abaixo resposta para se o saldo não for o tanto necessario:

```
if ($precodoproduto == "'.$saldo.'" && $saldo != "'.$precodoproduto") {

$error = '    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
if (!confirm('Você não tem pontos//moedas suficientes para efetuar está compra'))
{
history.back();
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>';
echo "$error";

}
```

Função if:

> [PHP.NET](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0):

Quando o usuário selecionar o produto, você pode fazer uma requisição AJAX pra verificar se ele tem saldo, com base na verificação você pode (ou não) mostrar o alerta.

Veja : [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: No <a href="#"> imagem </a>
Qual evento eu posso usar ali ao clicar nesse link, fazer uma requisição ajax?

Essa requisição eu posso chamar um arquivo PHP pra mim poder verificar e fazer todo o calculo lá?

Comment: Use o **click** (jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/click/
Sim a intenção é exatamente esta, o php te retorna se ele tem saldo e você continua a execução da aplicação.

Comment: Sempre prefira colocar toda informação possível na resposta, por isso a edição é permitida. Os comentários não são indexados pelos buscadores e dificulta ajudar outras pessoas no futuro que é nosso objetivo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você não quiser sair da página em que está, use uma chamada Ajax. Desta forma, é executado novo código PHP sem pedir para carregar a página outra vez.

Vou-lhe dar um exemplo simples que pode adaptar. Aqui está o link do seu produto:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="verificar_saldo();">imagem</a>
```

O seu link passa a chamar uma função javascript. Dentro dessa função tem a chamada Ajax, como mostro de seguida. Por Ajax é chamado o ficheiro seu_ficheiro_ajax.php, que vai fazer os cálculos que você precisa em PHP. Se necessitar retornar algo, faça-o com o comando "echo" dentro do ficheiro Ajax, esse retorno ficará na variável de javascript "html".

```
function verificar_saldo()
{

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "seu_ficheiro_ajax.php",
    data:   {
                parametro_1 : variavel_js1,
                parametro_2 : variavel_js2
            },
    cache: false,
success: function(html)
    {
        // seu código javascript/jquery a ser executado com o retorno (html) da chamada Ajax

        if(html >= 20) alert("ERRO: passou o seu limite");
    }
});

}
```

**Nota**

Como está usando jQuery, não se esqueça de colocar dentro do head da página o include de jQuery, como por exemplo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: TigerNuno, pra mim entender melhor sobre o que você usou, pois sou iniciante no ajax, por exemplo:
O que seria: (data:) e o que tem dentro dela: (data:   {
                parametro_1 : variavel_js1,
                parametro_2 : variavel_js2
            },  )
Esse cache ?

Tem como explicar linha por linha?

Obrigado!!

Comment: Claro que sim, explico o que você tiver dúvida. Sabe bem javascript? parametro_1 e parametro_2 são os parâmetros enviados através de POST, daí estarem dentro de data. Aqui dentro você pode adicionar mais parâmetros a serem enviados se necessitar. Você coloca em parâmetro_1 uma variável javascript com o valor que precisar, variavel_js1. Depois, no ficheiro Ajax "seu_ficheiro_ajax.php", vai buscar estes valores usando $_POST['parametro_1']. Espero ter sido claro. Qualquer outra dúvida, pergunte.